# Two apps reading/writing the same text file

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-services

I've got a Windows Service app that writes a log to a text file, and then I've got a WinForms app that needs to read the same information from the file.

But how can I get both apps (in the same solution) to read/write the same file?
Both apps' use a Shared project in the same solution, but the

```
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\log.txt";
```

for both points to different directory.

Comment: why not use a logPath config setting if you'll need to access the resource from multiple applications in the same solution?

Comment: This is a terrible idea. You should not have two processes writing to the same file. If only because the reliability of such code is dubious, whilst an unreliable log is completely utterly useless.

Comment: @Aron - it is the same class that both reads and writes the log.  The writing part is just called from the Win Service project, and the reading class from another project.  But it's the same class, in 1 project.

Comment: @user1208908 That isn't a log. It is IPC over FileSystem. It is an antipattern which is even worse than IPC over RDBMS, except in the case of implementation via Memory Mapped Files. Please look at other IPC technologies, such as WCF Named Pipes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a common path, try using:

```
string folderPath1 = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
// or 
string folderPath2 = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
```